# Django polls tutorial - would like to delete and start again

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, mezzanine

I'm working through the django 1.6 tutorial here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/

Various things have gone wrong along the line (the database now contains several non-functioning entries) and what I'd really like to do would be to blow away all traces of the "polls" app and start again, without deleting everything else in the database.

My database is postgresql. I've tried running python manage.py sqlclear polls and deleting the polls app files, but when I run through the tutorial again, the same duff information is still in the database from the time before.

Thanks for your help,

Julian

Comment: All the `sql*` management commands simply *print* SQL queries, they do not run them.

Comment: when you say "in the database" ... did you `CREATE DATABASE` a separate database for the "polls" app? Or are you using a database that contains tables for this app and other apps? It's a *really good idea* to always use a separate database for things like tutorials and testing.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to clear the polls table from your database then you can use

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

to get into a database shell and then execute sql commands

```
DROP TABLE poll_polls
```

you could also just enter a db shell from the command line, but the management command handles logging you in and selecting the correct database.

Comment: Hi - ./manage.py dbshell gives me:
"CommandError: You appear not to have the 'sqlite3' program installed or on your path."
As far as I understand it, the database is postgresql i.e. settings.py specifies:
"ENGINE": "django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2". I've re-done the tutorial with a different name and all has worked well but I'd like to be able to do a proper DROP TABLE poll_polls as you suggest.
Thanks for your help

Comment: I get an "interactive shell" by typing "python manage.py shell" but at that prompt typing DROP TABLE poll_polls simply gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having some problem deleting polls app files with command line you can manually delete your polls app tables in postgresql. Probabily they will be in *'db_name'/public/tables*.